# How to see the location pin on the map in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, geolocation, location

I am making small app in flutter. My app shows the houses / property for rent. All the data comes from `api`. Now I want to show the `Location` pin where the house is located. Current Latitude and Longitude fetch from the api. On the basis of fetched `Latitude and Longitude`, I just want to pin that on maps as below :

[image]

I want to achieve this in flutter. Can anybody guides me regarding this how to show this Location part?

Comment: Reminder that asking for tutorials is off-topic, see [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page. Given that a Google codelab exists for this topic: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter?hl=en#0 it would be better to search, make an attempt and then ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use marker for creating such type of things

```
`markers: {
  Marker(
    markerId: const MarkerId("marker1"),
    position: const LatLng(37.422131, -122.084801),
    draggable: true,
    onDragEnd: (value) {
      // value is the new position
    },
    // To do: custom marker icon
  ),
  
  Marker(
    markerId: const MarkerId("marker2"),
    position: const LatLng(37.415768808487435, -122.08440050482749),
  ),
},`
```

Some Thing like this or if you want to create custom marker then try like below

```
BitmapDescriptor markerIcon = BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker;
@override
void initState() {
  addCustomIcon();
  super.initState();
}
void addCustomIcon() {
  BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
          const ImageConfiguration(), "assets/Location_marker.png")
      .then(
    (icon) {
      setState(() {
        markerIcon = icon;
      });
    },
  );
}
```

If you want detail information about this you can visit this link [click here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-google-map-with-custom-marker-ea1555a37342)

Hope its solve your problem